# How to modify these VBA codes to save excel sheet in excel format (.xlsx)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I have added a button in excel sheet and now when I click that button it saves the sheet at specific path with specific name but in pdf format.

I want to save this sheet simply in excel format (.xlsx). so

```
Sub PDFActiveSheet2()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strFile As String

On Error GoTo errHandler

strFile = "m:\formats\" & Range("H8")
Set ws = ActiveSheet

ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=strFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

MsgBox "file has been created."

exitHandler:
        Exit Sub
errHandler:
        MsgBox "Could not create the file"
        Resume exitHandler

End Sub
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Change your following code from

```
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=strFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

To the following code

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\46506090\Desktop\Book1.xlsm", _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```

Change the path (**C:\Users\46506090\Desktop\Book1.xlsm**) to what you would want and see if it works.

```
CreateBackup:=False
```

This is optional

## Edit:

The complete code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()
'Sub PDFActiveSheet2()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strFile As String

On Error GoTo errHandler

strFile = "m:\formats\" & Range("H8")
Set ws = ActiveSheet

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\46506090\Desktop\Book1.xlsm", _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
'Comment: Replace "C:\Users\46506090\Desktop\Book1.xlsm" to your desired filename
MsgBox "file has been created."

exitHandler:
        Exit Sub
errHandler:
        MsgBox "Could not create the file"
        Resume exitHandler

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Prasanna, thanks for your kind help. But the codes are not working. it is giving error. So please give me full codes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ramji added the complete code. See if this works out for you. If not get in touch with me at prasannarajaram@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Correction to other answer there should be only one save location

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()
'Sub PDFActiveSheet2()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strFile As String

On Error GoTo errHandler

strFile = "C:\Users\yourName\Desktop\Book1.xlsm"
'Comment: Replace "C:\Users\yourName\Desktop\Book1.xlsm" to your desired filename

Set ws = ActiveSheet

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFile, _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

MsgBox "file has been created."

exitHandler:
        Exit Sub
errHandler:
        MsgBox "Could not create the file"
        Resume exitHandler

End Sub
```